# Manual Event Registration problems

Tags: civievent, registration

I'm trying to manually register a participant for a specific event, but the registration form is showing custom profiles that I've created for completely unrelated events. I'm unable to complete the manual registration until I've made a selection for all these required fields. This particular event does not use the profiles being show or show these profile questions on the public registration page, they only appear in the manual event registration page, below the Registration Confirmation and Receipt section. I don't see any mention of this in the manual (https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/events/manual-event-registration/), which makes me wonder if it's a bug.

How are these profiles getting here and how can I get rid of them without completely deleting them from my database?

I'm running CiviCRM 5.8.2 on Drupal.

Comment: It's understandable if you don't want to post a link to the event registration page in question, but if you do it would probably help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just wondering - you are saying Profiles - are you absolutely certain you aren't referring to a 'group of custom fields'. This would make sense if you have added lots of groups of custom fields and set them to apply for 'all' events. they would then show for a back end registration.

If so there are two steps to consider

a/ do not make custom fields 'required' - only set them to required in the profile

b/ set the 'group of custom fields' so they only apply to certain Event Types

Comment: You are absolutely right, I misunderstood where this information was coming from and it was actually 'group of custom fields'. I set required to 'no' for each of these fields, and everything is working like I expected. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Another step to consider: If those two steps don't work for you, you can use the same public-facing event registration form that the public would use. Just make sure you aren't logged in when you do it (otherwise you can overwrite your own CiviCRM info). We've found that sometimes it's just easier to do it this way when you need a specific profile to be available. Otherwise I don't think that the profiles show up when you're using the back-end system, just the custom fields you've specifically made required for events.